# Twitter bootstrap - Add animation / transition effect to tabbed navigation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a basic tabbed navigation using the example from the bootstrap site. how can i add an animation effect (fade in and out) so when each tab is clicked the new content is faded in?

```
 <!--   i have a basic tabbed navigation using the example from the bootstrap site. how can i add an animation effect (fade in and out) so when each tab is clicked the new content is faded in? -->

    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked span3">
         <li class="active">
          <a href="#myDashboardNav" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
        My dashboard 
        <span class="badge badge-important">20%</span>
            </a>

    </li>
    <li id="myfeed">
    <a href="#myFeedNav" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>
    My feed   
    <span class="badge badge-important">6</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li id="notifications">
    <a href="#notificationsNav" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="icon-time"></i>
    Notifications <span class="badge badge-important">9</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content span8">
    <div class="tab-pane well active" id="myDashboardNav" style="height: 330px">Content1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane well" id="myFeedNav" style="height: 330px">Content2

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane well" id="notificationsNav" style="height: 330px">Content3

    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Post any code that you've tried, and we'll try to help you work through it.

Comment: code posted.. i'm just using the basic example of tabbed nav from bootstrap twitter site, i want to click each tab and rather than flick to the tab content, i want it to fade in and out. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For transitions to work, the class "fade" should be added on all tab-panes and class "in" on the active pane. (The code below is an example from Bootstrap, edited to include transitions)

**Note**: This code is for Bootstrap 2. For v3, see the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">...</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is the real answer I need !

Comment: Just in case you are using Bootstrap 4 - Use "show" class instead of "in". Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to give your .tab-pane elements a `fade` class as [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) on the Twitter Bootstrap's official page explains.

```
<div class="tab-pane active fade in" ...>
```

Don't forget to load `bootstrap-transition.js`.

Comment: this doesn't work for me and I need it too. do I need to load also bootstrap-tabs? thanks

Comment: Works perfectly for me. If you want tabs, then yes you need to load tabs. If you want transitions then yes you need to load transitions. Whatever you need simply include or include everything by default and then simply remove JS you don't need after you finish building your site.

Answer (score 0):

Use history.pushState or History.js or build off of https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

This process is actually a pretty complicated and more advanced process than it might seem.

My site at http://cameronspear.com uses a variation of this to AJAX in the content while updating the URL and transitioning with a nice slide effect.

A simpler alternative, you could put all of the content on one page, and give each section a unique id, and a common class, and then make the links in the nav correspond to the unique IDs and with jQuery, hide the other content areas and show the one that was clicked.

Here's a simple sample of that: http://codepen.io/CWSpear/pen/naJzl

Comment: CWSspear, can you please give an example

Comment: The user asked how to do it with twitter. Twitter has this functionality built in and he simply needs to add a couple classes as another user noted and include transitions and tabs js that comes with Twitter Bootstrap.